# Convert newElm Buttons to list Buttons

Tags: javascript, button

What i am trying to do is converting buttons that are normaly created like this:

```
    for (i = 0; i < zahlen.length; i++) {
        newElm = document.createElement('button');
    newElm.className = 'zahlenknopf';
    newElm.onclick = function() {addiere(this); };
    newElm.innerHTML = zahlen[i];
    container.appendChild(newElm);
```

into five Buttons which are created by a list. So basically like this:

```
<ul class = "zahlenknopf">

          <li>onclick = function() {addiere(this);</li>
          <li>onclick = function() {addiere(this);</li>
          <li>onclick = function() {addiere(this);</li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>

</ul>
```

However: Even when fully written my coding programm of choice shows mistakes. I am no pro enough to understand my mistake. Can somebody help?

Comment: Could you please create some example (on jsfiddle.net or codepen.io)? I'm not sure i quite understand what are you aiming to do. What does "buttons which are created by a list" mean?

Comment: certain elements in your code is not clear. what is `zahlen`? how is this identified?

Comment: `zahlen` is a array incuding five random numbers which should than be written on the five buttons. I am a beginner with java script and i created a list of buttons in the past in order to than further work with it.                          [link] This looked like this https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=PheeMcu7nc. What i am now trying to do is to do this again. So to not generate the buttons but i have them in an list, while keepin the functions in the script i posted above. However i dont know if this can generally work out.

Answer (score 0):

Am still unclear as to what exactly you are trying here, but the following code inserts the button

```
 <ul class='foo'>
 </ul>
```

```js
(function() {
  var zahlen = [1,2,3,4,5]; // not sure what this is - just had it here from what i understood from your comment
  var uls = document.getElementsByClassName('foo');
  if (uls && uls.length) {
    for (i = 0; i < zahlen.length; i++) {
      var newLi = document.createElement('li');
      var newElm = document.createElement('button');
      newElm.className = 'zahlenknopf';
      newElm.onclick = function() {
        alert('clicked'); // just for demo - remove this alert later
        addiere(this);
      };
      newElm.innerHTML = zahlen[i];
      newLi.appendChild(newElm);
      uls[0].appendChild(newLi);
    }
  }
}());
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jayas_godblessall/nbvhdysz/